# With security keyguard active transition between activities is weird

Tags: android, android-activity, android-windowmanager, keyguard, keyguardlock

I have my main activity A and when the user presses a button i open another activity B. But when this happens B doesn't just appear on top of A:

- A disappears
- secure keyguard shows up
- B appears

And when i get rid of B the same thing happens. This is annoying because there's a lot of flickering with no real purpose on the screen. Is there any way to achieve direct transition from A to B while keyguard is active without merging the 2 activities into 1?

Here is what i'm doing in onCreate for both activities:

```
getWindow().addFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

And here is how i start the activity:

```
        final Intent intent = new Intent(Sand.this, EditRule.class);
        intent.putExtra(DB.KEY_PARENT_ID, id);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

I also tried setting a null android:windowAnimationStyle in the activity theme but no luck.

**UPDATE**: i submitted this bug:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68465&thanks=68465&ts=1397301860

Thanks,
Teo

Comment: Same issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22389765/lockscreen-is-displayed-between-activities) but no solution yet. I'll be interested to see if you find a solution.

Comment: I was beginning to think i'm the only one on the planet with this problem :) i'm actually looking for a solution for over a year now. I saw a really subtle effect with Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION which in my tests makes the 'flicker' just a bit faster but doesn't eliminate it. If at the end of the bounty there's no solution i think i'll submit a bug.

Comment: Just making sure I understand this, when you transition between Activity A and Activity B, your lock screen pops up, then closes, then your new activity pops up?

Comment: Have you had the opportunity to look at this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22389765/lockscreen-is-displayed-between-activities

Comment: Yes that's what happens (and i saw that post, Randy linked to the same post in the first comment :) i tried everything in it, no luck. If there's really no solution i think it's safe to look at it as a bug because the focus is 'stolen' by the keyguard. The app doesn't lose focus if the keyguard is unlocked. IMHO maybe the way of setting WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED flags per activity is the problem. Until the activity has time to set these flags a part of it has already loaded without these flags...

Comment: ... so the keyguard thinks it's ok to come in front. Maybe we should be able to set these flags on the whole application somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into this extensively (with a couple other engineers) a year or so ago on ICS and JB. It was not possible to avoid the flicker, which I strongly suspect is still the case in KitKat.  You should file that bug.

(If you look at the Keyguard-related source in Android, it's a rather.. *hefty* mass of code/policy riddled with special cases.  Since this case isn't explicitly documented anywhere, even if you can get it to work on one version, I would not rely on it working consistently.)

Ultimately, we worked around the issue by combining all of our must-not-flicker lockscreen UI into a single Activity.  It was unpleasant, but it worked.