# Start an activity with FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED. The previous activity disappears and slides in again

Tags: android-activity, android-5.0-lollipop

I lock the device screen, start the activity `LockAct`. `LockAct` starts another activity which has a `SurfaceView`.

If I don't add `<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>` to the activity with the `SurfaceView`, neither `surfaceCreated` nor `surfaceChanged` will be called.

If I add `<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>` to the activity with the `SurfaceView`, `LockAct` disappears and slides in on **Android 5.0 only** as shown [in the video.](http://youtu.be/lXmkZKdJR-U) It looks ugly.

How to prevent `LockAct` from disappearing and sliding in again?

What I've already tried:

**ActivityOptions for LockAct**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LockAct.class);
startActivity(intent, ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(getApplicationContext(), 0, 0).toBundle());
```

**android:windowAnimationStyle for LockAct**

```
<style name="NoAnim" parent="@style/AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
</style>

<activity android:name="com.admin.LockAct"
    android:theme="@style/NoAnim" />
```

**android:windowEnterTransition and android:windowExitTransition for LockAct**

```
<style name="NoAnim" parent="@style/AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowEnterTransition">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitTransition">@null</item>
</style>

<activity android:name="com.admin.LockAct"
    android:theme="@style/NoAnim" />
```

Here is an archive with my sample Android app: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mc4pzqwc2o8lsej/Sample-Android-Lock.rar?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activities are not started or finished smoothly when the device screen is locked. I noticed that on Android 5.0, but everything looks pretty good on my Samsung Galaxy S3 with CyanogenMod (Android 4.3.1). So different behavior may be on different devices and/or OS versions.

A co-worker gave me the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/23022023/1065835, and I'm going to use fragments instead of activities.